# tikz overlay combined with baseline

Tags: tikz-pgf

When I use the `baseline` key in an `overlay` TikZ picture the picture suddenly has a nonzero depth:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}[t]{4cm}
abc\\
abc\tikz[overlay,opacity=0.5,red,baseline={(3,3)}]\filldraw (0,0)rectangle (3,3);def\\
abc
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Is this a bug?

## Edit

I have made a bug report https://sourceforge.net/p/pgf/bugs/345/. I'm not sure that it is a real bug but imho at least the documentation should mention this side effect of baseline.

Comment: When you put `baseline={(1,1)}` you can see that what is "overlayed" is only the part over the baseline ... combined with `use as bounding box` you can make it "overlayed" under the baseline, but I have no idea if it is a bug.

Comment: @Kpym well actually the "non-overlay" part is between (0,0) and the baseline. What do mean with `use as bounding box`? I did put it everywhere I can think of but it didn't change the behaviour.

Comment: sorry, you are right. Everything between the baseline and 0 is not overlayed even when we use `\pgfresetboundingbox` at the end of the picture (what is probably doing 'overlay' option).It looks more like a bug for me.

Answer (score 6):

I wouldn't consider this as a bug because they have completely orthogonal usage. The reason why suddenly depth is introduced is because that's what baseline does. This comes from the fact that baseline introduces modifications to `\pgf@picminy` and `\pgf@picmaxy`. Which are otherwise set to 16000 and -16000 respectively and tested accordingly (though only max is tested because any point modifies the max anyhow). The relevant part of `\endpgfpicture` is

```
          % Shift baseline outside:
          \pgf@relevantforpicturesizefalse% 
          \pgf@process{\pgf@baseline}\showthe\pgf@y%
          \xdef\pgf@shift@baseline{\the\pgf@y}%
```

Instead you can use a suitable transformation as Paul Gaborit showed (which are local to the picture and does not leak out to the external placement mechanism);

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}[t]{4cm}
abc\\
abc\tikz[overlay,
         opacity=0.5,red,
         shift={(-1.5,-1.5)}]
      \filldraw (0,0)rectangle (3,3);def\\
abc
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: In this example shift works but in the real case the baseline were set as (A.north) so the shifting value wasn't known. And if it is not bug then imho there should a very large warning in the documentation that `baseline` interferes with the bounding box. You get the same problem with `use as bounding box`: `\tikz[opacity=0.5,red,baseline={(3,3)}]{\path[use as bounding box](0,0); \filldraw (0,0)rectangle (3,3);}`

Comment: @UlrikeFischer This is independent of the bounding box but in your example use as bounding box should come as the last path to override the previous drawings. However it would still not work because baseline is the outer TikZ object positioning that would still have a depth even if the inner picture has zero bounding box.

Comment: No, the `use as bounding box` must come first as tikz doesn't shrink an existing bounding box: "However, if there were previous
path operations that have already established a larger bounding box, it will not be made smaller by this operation". And I do understand the technical argument. But it doesn't feel right that an overlay has a depth, and that there seem to be no tikz option to force an null size picture and that one has to use an outside command like `\raisebox` or `smash`.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Sorry I forgot to add `\pgfresetboundingbox`. One can also argue that these keys are not meant to be used together. Because if I change the rectangle coordinate to `(-3,-3)` in your example in the question then The bounding box is somewhere else but we are raising the baseline down. They are all ambiguous cases to me.

Comment: Imho with `use as bounding box` you are right: If I move a null size object down if can/should affect the line spacing. But `overlay` should lead to an overlay. But is as it is. So how would you solve the actual problem with tikz tools (without a lot of fuzz)? I want an overlay that doesn't disturb the surrounding text. And I want that the coordinate (A.north) is placed on the baseline.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I'll check the `(A.north)` usage asap.

Answer (score 4):

It seems that it is a bug (in my point of view). You may emulate `baseline` via `yshift` (using `-3cm`):

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\noindent abc\\
abc\tikz[opacity=0.5,red,overlay,yshift=-3cm]\filldraw (0,0)rectangle (3,3);def\\
abc
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

In any case, you can achieve the same effect using `\rlap` and `\raisebox`.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}[t]{4cm}
abc\\
abc\rlap{\raisebox{-\height}[0pt][0pt]%
{\tikz[opacity=0.5,red]{\filldraw (0,0)rectangle (3,3);}}}def\\abc
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

[image: overlay]